# How to disable mouse using Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net, windows

I wrote a tech toolbox in autohotkey but a lot of AV software has been starting to kill things written in autohotkey so I am redoing it in VB .net 
I have been able to get most everything done but one of the tools that almost everyone that uses my toolbox uses is a hotkey that disables the mouse. We are working remotely using logmein and it just stops the customers from killing things like virus removal tools.

I have found a way to disable both mouse and keyboard using VB.net but it disables it completely instead of just for the customer, and I just want it to disable the mouse not the keyboard too because when it kills both the hotkey to enable them again does not work lol.

Here is what I have been using for code.

```
Private Declare Function GetAsyncKeyState Lib "user32" (ByVal vkey As Long) As Integer
Private Declare Function BlockInput Lib "user32" Alias "BlockInput" (ByVal fBlock As Integer) As Integer
Private Declare Function ShowCursor Lib "user32" (ByVal lShow As Long) As Long
Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    Timer1.Enabled = True
    Timer1.Interval = 1
    Dim mkey As Boolean
    Dim dkey As Boolean
    Dim ekey As Boolean
    mkey = GetAsyncKeyState(Keys.M)
    dkey = GetAsyncKeyState(Keys.D)
    ekey = GetAsyncKeyState(Keys.E)
    If mkey And dkey = True Then
        BlockInput(1)
        ShowCursor(0)
    End If

    If mkey And ekey = True Then
        BlockInput(0)
        ShowCursor(1)
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Don't use `Integer` and `Long` in `Declare` instructions (or p/invoke).  Instead, use `Int32` (or appropriate other sizes).  A good many of your declarations are wrong.

Comment: @BenVoigt that's totally correct (+1)

Answer (score 1):

```
Private Declare Function BlockInput Lib "user32" Alias "BlockInput" (ByVal fBlock As Integer) As Integer
```

To enable

```
BlockInput 1
```

To disable

```
BlockInput 0
```

Comment: dwb thats what it does right now and it blocks all input so you cant have a hotkey to disable and another to enable, also it does not allow actions through remote software to override it.

Comment: Can anyone give me any other ways because this way does not do what I need it disables the keyboard as well as the mouse.